# Shut down the port when someone plug out the cable

Tags: switch, security, cable, port-security

We have Cisco Catalyst 2960-S switches,

And we noticed some employees plug out the internet cables to connect them to their Lab top.

I want the command that I can use to make the port shutdown when someone plug out the cable from the PC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as block port administratively when it comes down operationally. Though as you mentioned in the tags, you can use port security for that and configure maximum MAC addresses per port. For example:

```
interface X
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security maximum 1
 switchport port-security violation shutdown
```

Violation mode defaults to shutdown, so this line is optional

Answer (score 0):

Put the switch in a locked closet, or, get a wallmount lock box for it.
[image]